# How to create user specific data when user logs in for the first time in realtime firebase database?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I want the code to behave such that it creates specific data when user is signed in but doesn't create it if already present in the firebase real-time database.
I have used the following code through which i check if the child is already present or not and if not then creates the child in firebase database, but somehow  the code isn't behaving as it should.
Whenev the user logins again the complete data part is rewritten.

**Snippet I need help in**

```
if (!(checkdata(user.uid))) {
            writeUserData(user.uid,user.displayName,user.email,user.photoURL)
        }
var database = firebase.database();

function checkdata(userid){
    var ref = firebase.database().ref("users");
ref.once("value")
  .then(function(snapshot) {
    var datapresent = snapshot.hasChild(userid); // true
    return datapresent
  });
}
function writeUserData(userId, name, email, imageUrl) {
    firebase.database().ref('users/' + userId).set({
      username: name,
      email: email,
      profile_picture : imageUrl,
      cropdata : []
      
    });
  }
```

**Complete JS file**

```
const signInBtn = document.getElementById('signinbtn');
const signOutBtn = document.getElementById('signoutbtn');
const userDetails = document.getElementById('username');

const auth = firebase.auth();
const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();

signInBtn.onclick = () => auth.signInWithPopup(provider);

signOutBtn.onclick = () => auth.signOut();

function toggle(className, displayState){
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName(className)

    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
        elements[i].style.display = displayState;
    }
}

auth.onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
    if (user) {
        // signed in
        toggle('userishere', 'block');
        toggle('usernothere', 'none');
        //userDetails.innerHTML = `<h3>Hello ${user.displayName}!</h3> <p>User ID: ${user.uid}</p>`;
        userDetails.innerHTML = `Hello ${user.displayName}!`
        console.log(user)
        if (!(checkdata(user.uid))) {
            writeUserData(user.uid,user.displayName,user.email,user.photoURL)
        }
    } else {
        // not signed in
        toggle('userishere', 'none');
        toggle('usernothere', 'block');
        userDetails.innerHTML = '';
    }
});


var database = firebase.database();

function checkdata(userid){
    var ref = firebase.database().ref("users");
ref.once("value")
  .then(function(snapshot) {
    var datapresent = snapshot.hasChild(userid); // true
    return datapresent
  });
}
function writeUserData(userId, name, email, imageUrl) {
    firebase.database().ref('users/' + userId).set({
      username: name,
      email: email,
      profile_picture : imageUrl,
      cropdata : []
      
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I just found the solution, the asynchronous code wasn't waiting for my firebase response and just checeked if datapresent was true or not, so with a async definition before function and await before ref.once(value) does the trick and my problem is solve. Working code below :

```
const signInBtn = document.getElementById('signinbtn');
const signOutBtn = document.getElementById('signoutbtn');
const userDetails = document.getElementById('username');
var database = firebase.database();
const auth = firebase.auth();
const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();



signInBtn.onclick =  () => auth.signInWithPopup(provider);

signOutBtn.onclick =  () => auth.signOut();

async function checkdata(user){
    let ref = firebase.database().ref("users");
    let snapshot = await ref.once('value');
    if (!snapshot.hasChild(user.uid)){
        console.log(user)
        writeUserData(user.uid,user.displayName,user.email,user.photoURL)
        console.log("write done")
    }
    else{
        console.log("did not write")
    }
}

function writeUserData(userId, name, email, imageUrl) {
    firebase.database().ref('users/' + userId).set({
        username: name,
        email: email,
        profile_picture: imageUrl,
        cropdata: []
    });
}


function toggle(className, displayState) {
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName(className)

    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        elements[i].style.display = displayState;
    }
}

auth.onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
    if (user) {
        // signed in
        toggle('userishere', 'block');
        toggle('usernothere', 'none');
        //userDetails.innerHTML = `<h3>Hello ${user.displayName}!</h3> <p>User ID: ${user.uid}</p>`;
        userDetails.innerHTML = `Hello ${user.displayName}!`
        console.log(user)
        checkdata(user)
    }
    else {
        toggle('userishere', 'none');
        toggle('usernothere', 'block');
        userDetails.innerHTML = '';
    }
})
```